# Триггер на получение сообщения в мессенджере

Tags: клиент-сервер

Занимаюсь созданием примитивного мессенджера. Условно, есть 2 клиента и между ними сервер. Первый пользователь должен отправить сообщение, оно должно загрузиться на сервер и, если второй клиент в сети, то он get-запросом получает это сообщение.

Не могу понять, как при появлении на сервере нового сообщения дать об этом понять второму клиенту

Comment: Самое простое: SSE - https://learn.javascript.ru/server-sent-events

Comment: Чуть сложное, но абсолютно идентичное - веб сокеты. Читай, наслаждайся)

Comment: Если это мессенджер, то лучше сразу на сокетах все это делать

Comment: На сокетах нашёл только решение, когда пользователи по-очереди отправляют и принимают сообщения